# Convert .jar to .war

Tags: java, eclipse, class, jar, war

How do I convert `.jar` to `.war` file format.

Basically I want to read the `file.jar`. But when I import in eclipse, it obviously imports as `.class` files. I want to read in `.java` format and read the code.

Kindly help

Comment: Does the .jar contains .java source code files? If so, Eclipse should show them to you. You can check by opening the jar file with unzip. If not, there is no source... And what does this have to do with .war ?

Comment: you can either download the source code from net if its open source or use a decompiler.

Comment: The first and second sentence of your question suggest that you might have the wrong idea of what a `war` file is. Converting a `jar` to a `war` is not going to help you to see the source code of the classes.

Answer (score 1):

Please remember that .jar and .war are different file formats. Even though, they are zipped set of files, a war file has  a [standard organization structure](https://learn.it.uts.edu.au/aip/enrolled/03-servlets/images/war_file_structure.png) . Where as a jar file is simple a standard zip archive of files generally used as packaged binary archive. What you are trying to do is difficult to achieve and there are no straight forward way to do that. You will have to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

As @Santosh says, war and jar are the same compression (so you can rename it to jar and use jar -x to uncompress it) but the internal organization is different. It seems to me like you just want to fish out the java files, so uncompressing would suffice...

```
mv file.war file.jar
jar xf file.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

If the reason you are trying to convert a `jar` to a `war` is only because you want to be able to see the source code of the classes in the `jar`, then trying to convert it to a `war` is not the right thing to do.

A Java `jar` (Java ARchive) file is just like a zip file, an archive that can contain other files. Normally it will contain `class` files (compiled Java classes). A `war` (Web ARchive) is the same as a `jar` file, but with a certain prescribed directory structure that makes it suitable for deployment on a Java EE application server. Converting a `jar` file to a `war` file will not automatically make it possible to see the source code of the classes in Eclipse.

To see the sources in Eclipse, you'll need to download those sources separately. For many open source projects, you can get the sources in a separate `jar`. For example, for the library `somelib.jar` you might find `somelib-sources.jar` or something similar from the website where you got the library.

Then, in Eclipse, right-click the `jar` file that's attached to your project as a dependency and select Properties from the popup menu. Then go to "Java Source Attachment". Enter the location of the `...-sources.jar` or a directory that contains the source code there and click OK.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement implies that your `file.jar` doesn't contain Java Code.

Here I suggest to you.

1. Differ `.jar` and `.war` file format. It is already on previous answer.
2. If you want to read the code from your `file.jar`, actually you can decompile it first. There are many Java decompiler that is easy to use. I suggest you use [JD](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) for this purpose.